# Replacing letters from input with a cycled item in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, encryption

In Python, I'm trying to write a Python script that replaces each letter with a cycled item from a list.

For example:

```
input = "aaaabbbb"
list_a = ["B,C,D"]
list_b = ["1,2,3"]
```

prints `BCDB1231`

**OR**

```
input = "aaaaaaaaa"
list_a = ["b","c","d"]
```

prints `bcdbcdbcd`.

- If `a` in input, replace a with cycled item from list_a.
- If `b` in input, replace b with cycled item from list_b.

Comment: @retep Have you already tried to write code for this? If so, what is going wrong? SO is _not_ a code writing service.

Comment: The list should be `list_a = ["B","C","D"]`

Comment: How does "aaaa" translate into "BCDB"? If every character in the input message is the same, I would expect every character in the encrypted message to be the same. Or is that not the actual expected output, and you were just giving an example of what the English text would look like and just put down random letters for the encrypted part? Please provide expected output that is the actual expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easy once you understand what you want.
If you need to cycle the letters, use `itertools.cycle` function

```
list_a = ['B', 'C', 'D']
my_input = 'aaaa'

output = ''.join(x for x,a in zip(itertools.cycle(list_a), my_input))
```

Probably you want to encode several letters, so you should create a dictionary with all of then, like this:

```
encode_data = {
    'a': itertools.cycle(['B', 'C', 'D']),
    'b': itertools.cycle(['X', 'Y', 'Z']),
    ...
}
```

And access like this:

```
output = ''.join(next(encode_data[x]) for x in 'aaabbb')
```

Comment: Great Thanks! If I wanted to decrypt it, would I do `output.replace('B','a')`

Comment: @retep You would need to replace every letter mapping to 'a'. In this case 'B', 'C' and 'D'.

Comment: Thanks! I got my encoder and decoder to work with `26!` possible options